# A theorem whose proof involved a concept called "large prime numbers"

Tags: notation, soft-question

(I apologize if this question is not adequate for this site. On doubt i decided to ask it anyway.)

I remember some theorem / proof of a theorem that used some concept called "large primes", and i think the proof ended by showing those primes don't exist. Unfortunately those are all details i can remember of.

Does anyone know a proof that goes like this? Searching "large prime" in internet doesn't seem to return any revelant result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer: [Erdős' proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Proofs) of $$\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1p=\infty$$ uses such a concept. By way of contradiction, he assumes the sum is finite, and partitions the set of primes into large primes and small primes, such that the sum $\sum\frac1p$ over the large primes is less than $\frac12$.